# Remove formatting from Java String while retaining accented characters

Tags: java, string, unicode-string

How can I remove the formatting in the Java String, while retaining the accented characters?

See example below. My goal is to get öwnNämé@gmail.com (note how . has changed to gmail.com)

```
String formattedStr = "öwnNämé@.";
for(int i=0; i < formattedStr.length(); i++) {
   System.out.print(formattedStr.charAt(i));
}
```

This is the output of the above. (Oddly, if I use `print` instead of `println`, it prints fine)

```
ö
w
n
N
ä
m
é
@
?
?
?
?
?
?
?
?
?
?
.
?
?
?
?
?
?
```

If instead of `formattedStr.charAt(i)` I use `Integer.toHexString(formattedStr.codePointAt(i))`, this is the output

```
f6
77
6e
4e
e4
6d
e9
40
1d5f4
ddf4
1d5fa
ddfa
1d5ee
ddee
1d5f6
ddf6
1d5f9
ddf9
2e
1d5f0
ddf0
1d5fc
ddfc
1d5fa
ddfa
```

Comment: Do you really want to change the mathematical bold g to an ASCII g, or do you just want to print each character?

Comment: My goal is to convert this String to öwnNämé@gmail.com (change to ASCII g etc)

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your issue by using [`Normalizer.Form.NFKC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.Form.html#NFKC):

```
String response = Normalizer.normalize(formattedStr, Normalizer.Form.NFKC);
```

This will return a String without the bold characters and it will print.

```
ö
w
n
N
ä
m
é
@
g
m
a
i
l
.
c
o
m
```

Comment: Thank you! I'd never have known to look into this Normalizer thing!

Comment: You are welcome, yes it is a helpful library in those situations.

Answer (score 2):

The characters after the `@` have codepoints above 0xffff, so they won’t fit into a single `char` value.  Instead, each such character is represented as two `char` values, known as surrogates.  This encoding is known as UTF-16.  (When Java was created, Unicode only had 16-bit values, because no one imagined that more than 2¹⁶ codepoints would be needed.)

You can use [java.text.Normalizer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Normalizer.html) to convert characters to common forms.  The `NFKC` ([compatibility then composition](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Compatibility_Equivalence_Figure)) normalizer form will preserve accents and other diacritics.

```
String converted = Normalizer.normalize(formattedStr, Normalizer.Form.NFKC);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of NFKC